# Google Sheets, Suddenly decimalised some of my number entries

Tags: google-sheets

I've been using Google Sheets to create a record of car parts, entering:

- each part's serial number,
- the quantity of that particular part,
- the name of the part and
- the location where I'm storing the part.

I have entered over 800 different parts now with multiple numbers for each but looking back I have noticed that some of the amount numbers seem to have 'decimalised' at the start of the sheet. I have only been using whole numbers and the formatting on all the cells is set to plain text. I can redo the 70 or so that have corrupted but I'm worried that it could happen again.

Can anyone explain how I might prevent this happening?

Answer (score 2):

You can prepend the value with a single quote (`'`) and Google Spreadsheets would take that input as a string. Like `'19`.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way may be to ensure that the column is formatted as Plain text *before* any data entry. Automatic conversions, say from `0123` to `123`, take place on data entry and are "once off" - applying Text format to `123` does not revert to `0123` even if that was what was entered. (Google does not remember `0123` as such, even in Revision History.)